# All methods return '.autoNumeric is not a function - Can't unformat numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting, autonumeric.js

I'm trying to get the raw values of input numbers formatted using autoNumeric, but can't because every method I try to do this with it returning '*.autoNumeric is not a function*' in the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    new AutoNumeric('#input',  AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().numericPos.dotDecimalCharCommaSeparator);
    
    $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
     $('#output').val($('#input').autoNumeric('getString'));
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autonumeric/4.0.3/autoNumeric.js"></script>

<input id="input" name="basicPayPerYearInput" type="text" value="123456.78" placeholder="0.00" class="currencyInput validate">

<input type="text" for="basicPayPerYearInput" id="output">
```

I can't even initialise inputs properly as written in most of the documentation using `$(selector).autoNumeric()`, so I've had to use the above 'new AutoNumeric', which is strangely also used in some documentation and is the only way that works:

Comment: What does this have to do with concurrency? Sounds like you're missing a reference to the plugin either that or you have it in the wrong place.

Comment: Typed in currency and clicked on that by accident thinking it said currency

Comment: Your error message indicates that `autoNumeric()` is not a jQuery method (which is true, it's not dependent on jQuery). You seem to have read the old documentation (<v2) of autonumeric, which is a jQuery plugin. The later versions are not jQuery-dependent.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of the new documentation? I've had a good look and can't find anything anywhere that matches the non-jquery version. I just need to know what method to use to get a numeric string from an input value

Comment: @nick.cook See my answer. p/s: Their docs are *very* convoluted, but not surprising since it is a very powerful library. Check their [getter/setter](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#set-get-format-unformat-and-other-usual-autonumeric-functions) part of their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have been reading the documentation for the old API of AutoNumeric plugin. The plugin has been rewritten since them to be independent of jQuery, which means that `.autoNumeric()` is no longer a valid jQuery method.

What you want to do is to store the AutoNumeric instance at runtime, and then simply use the [getter method `.getNumericString()`](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#set-get-format-unformat-and-other-usual-autonumeric-functions) on the instance to retrieve its string value:

```
// Store instance
var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric('#input', AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().numericPos.dotDecimalCharCommaSeparator);

$('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    // Retrieve instance numeric string value
    $('#output').val(autoNumericInstance.getNumericString());
});
```

See proof-of-concept example here (or the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/0eax1feg/1/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric('#input', AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().numericPos.dotDecimalCharCommaSeparator);
    
    $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
     $('#output').val(autoNumericInstance.getNumericString());
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autonumeric/4.0.3/autoNumeric.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<input id="input" name="basicPayPerYearInput" type="text" value="123456.78" placeholder="0.00" class="currencyInput validate">

<input type="text" for="basicPayPerYearInput" id="output">
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know the instances needed to be stored as variables

Comment: @nick.cook You do not have to store them, for example, if it is a one-time setup and you don't plan to set/get anymore from it. But if you need to reference them later, you will have to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when you have defined your aNvariable with the static 'multiple' method (because you needed to). You need a different approach which I haven't found as yet. As powerful as the AutoNumeric library is, it severely lacks in understandable documentation. Proper examples for different usages would be extremely helpful. I am working on my own manual.

Answer (score 2):

@Terry answer is completely right regarding the question asked, however I recommend **not** using an event listener on your `#input` `keyup` event, since `AutoNumeric` does *not* always update the element value on each `keyup`, for instance when a *bad* key is entered by the user, ie. the key `A`.

If you want to update your `#output` element with the numeric string only when it *really* change, then you should listen to the custom event `'autoNumeric:rawValueModified'`, so:

instead of:

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#output').val(autoNumericInstance.getNumericString());
});
```

you should use:

```
const outputElm = document.querySelector('#output');
const inputElm = document.querySelector('#input');
inputElm.addEventListener('autoNumeric:rawValueModified', e => {
    outputElm.value = e.newRawValue;
});
```

The documentation about the [custom events](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/next#autonumeric-custom-events-details) sent by [AutoNumeric](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/next).
Also [checkout](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/next#using-callback-functions-with-get-methods) how you can add `callbacks` to all the `get*` functions.